# Select dependientes - Angular 9

Tags: angular

Estimados necesitó filtrar, `selects` dependientes en Angular 9, tengo este código me devuelve una descripción (`description`) y un código (`code`) nesecito enviar el código al otro `select`, para obtener la description o nombre de provincia, el tema es que es un solo `endpoint`.

 No se como pasar el código al otro `select`,

Me envían un `enpoint` único que por el `code` obtengo el otro valor es hacer un `select` en cascada,

Dejo lo que tengo. espero me puedan ayudar no se si me explique bien pero es lo que tengo.

en el método `onSelect()` en consola obtengo el código correcto, pero no se como enviárselo al otro `select` para que obtenga el nombre correspondiente espero este explicando bien.

```js
/* Servicio Inicio*/
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment.dev';
import { IUbigeo } from '@aafp/commons/interfaces';
import { Department, Province } from '../interfaces/ubigeo.interface';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class Ubigeo {

  public departamentos: Department[] = [];
  public provincias: Province[] = [];
  // ENDPOINTS
  private url = `${environment.url}/retiro4uit/v1/util4uit/util?code=ubigeo`;
  
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  
  getDepartamentos () {
    this.http.get(this.url)
      .subscribe( (resp: Department[]) => {
        console.log(resp, 'departamentos');
        this.departamentos = resp;
      });
  }
}
/* Servicio Fin*/

/* Componente Inicio*/
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { STEPPER_GLOBAL_OPTIONS } from '@angular/cdk/stepper';
import { Ubigeo } from '../../commons/http/ubigeo.http';
import { SELECT_ITEM_HEIGHT_EM } from '@angular/material/select';
import { Department, Province } from '../../commons/interfaces/ubigeo.interface';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-residente-aporte-step',
  templateUrl: './residente-aporte-step.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./residente-aporte-step.component.scss'],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: STEPPER_GLOBAL_OPTIONS,
      useValue: { displayDefaultIndicatorType: false },
    },
  ],
})
export class ResidenteAporteStepComponent implements OnInit {

  firstFormGroup: FormGroup;
  secondFormGroup: FormGroup;
  public formSubmitted = false;

  constructor(
    private _formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    public ubigeo: Ubigeo,
    ) {}
  
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.ubigeo.getDepartamentos();
  }

  // Cargando Datos del servicio 4uit localstorage
  firstName =  localStorage.getItem('firstName' || '').toLowerCase();
  amountAvailable =  localStorage.getItem('amountAvailable' || '');

  // carga Provincias
  onSelect(code: number): void {
    console.log(code);
  } 
}
/* Componente Fin*/
```

```html
<mat-form-field class="select-width">
    <mat-label>Departamento</mat-label>
    <select matNativeControl required [(ngModel)]="selectedDepartament.code" (change)="onSelect($event.target.value)">
        <option *ngFor="let departments of ubigeo.departamentos" value={{departments.code}}>{{departments.description | titlecase}}</option>
    </select>
</mat-form-field>

<mat-form-field class="select-width">
    <mat-label>Provincia</mat-label>
    <select matNativeControl required>
        <option value="Lima">Lima</option>
        <option value="Lima">Lima</option>
        <option value="Lima">Lima</option>
        <option value="Lima">Lima</option>
    </select>
</mat-form-field>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero a tu servicio agrega el siguiente método `getProvincias(code)` para obtener las provincias del departamento (lee los comentarios dentro del código):

```
export class Ubigeo {

  public departamentos: Department[] = [];
  public provincias: Province[] = [];
  // ENDPOINTS
  // retiramos el ubigeo y lo colocamos en getDepartamentos(), el parámetro code lo usaremos para obtener las provincias.
  private url = `${environment.url}/retiro4uit/v1/util4uit/util?code=`;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  // método que realizará la petición para obtener los departamentos
  getDepartamentos() {
    // acá ponemos el parámetro code = ubigeo para que te devuelva los departamentos
    this.http.get(this.url + 'ubigeo')
      .subscribe( (resp: Department[]) => {
        console.log(resp, 'departamentos');
        this.departamentos = resp;
      });
  }

  // método que realizará la petición para obtener las provincias de un departamento
  // code es el parámetro que recibe el método y que enviaremos como parámetro de endpoint en code 
  getProvincias(code: any) {
    // limpiamos las provincias
    this.provincias= [];
    // obtenemos las provincias con el parámetro code = code
    this.http.get(this.url + code)
      .subscribe( (resp: Province[]) => {
        console.log(resp, 'provincias');
        this.provincias = resp;
      });
  }
}
```

Luego en tu componente debes mandar a llamar al servicio para que obtenga las provincias:

```
export class ResidenteAporteStepComponent implements OnInit {

  firstFormGroup: FormGroup;
  secondFormGroup: FormGroup;
  public formSubmitted = false;

  constructor(
    private _formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    public ubigeo: Ubigeo,
    ) {}
  
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.ubigeo.getDepartamentos();
  }

  // Cargando Datos del servicio 4uit localstorage
  firstName =  localStorage.getItem('firstName' || '').toLowerCase();
  amountAvailable =  localStorage.getItem('amountAvailable' || '');

  // carga Provincias cambio tu parámetro a any, haz puesto tipo number, pero por lo que veo en consola es un string, no un número.
  onSelect(code: any): void {
    console.log(code);
    this.ubigeo.getProvincias(code); // con esto ya hemos obtenido las provincias del departamento seleccionado, ahora solo falta ponerlo en la plantilla html.
  } 
}
```

Entonces en tu plantilla finalmente solo debes recorrer las provincias...

```
<mat-form-field class="select-width">
    <mat-label>Departamento</mat-label>
    <select matNativeControl required [(ngModel)]="selectedDepartament.code" (change)="onSelect($event.target.value)">
        <option *ngFor="let departments of ubigeo.departamentos" value={{departments.code}}>{{departments.description | titlecase}}</option>
    </select>
</mat-form-field>

<mat-form-field class="select-width">
    <mat-label>Provincia</mat-label>
    <!-- recorremos las provincias con un *ngFor -->
    <select matNativeControl required>
        <option *ngFor="let province of ubigeo.provincias" value="{{province.code}}">{{province.description | titlecase}}</option>
    </select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Espero esto te sea de utilidad, y espero también solucione tus dudas.

Comment: Gracias , me sirvio. gracias por la ayuda.